# ReactJS imported component Cron overrides styles

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, cron, styled-components

I have noticed that my ReactJS app has changed the styles, especially fonts once I have imported `Cron` component from [react-cron-generator](https://github.com/sojinantony01/react-cron-generator):

```js
import Cron from 'react-cron-generator'
```

Looking into the code of [`cron.tsx`](https://github.com/sojinantony01/react-cron-generator/blob/master/src/lib/cron.tsx) I see that there are styles applied `import './cron-builder.css';` which from my perspective cause the issue, because it has:

```css
body {
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

I would like to understand how it can happen that such imported component can override my defined styles and how it should be imported to avoid it.

I was looking into the styled components, but the problem is, that my styles are always overridden once I do the `import Cron from 'react-cron-generator'`.

Is there a way how to fix it?

Comment: You could add `!important` to your own css for `body` `font-family`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles are applied based on how much their selector are detailed. check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more info. if an imported style has more detailed selector, its css class file is mentioned earlier or your styles are not as specific as that or you have not specified that selector, that imported style will apply.

And please don't use `important`. it may fix your problem but it is not a clean and maintainable solution although it is popular in css world.